# Can Dependencies look back to decide on next task?

Tags: dependencies, microsoft-project

Let say I have 20 walls that I need to paint in a given sequence.
Each wall needs 5 coats of paint and each application needs 12 hrs. to dry.
The walls have varying square footage and take varying hrs. to paint.
I need to complete the work by starting in sequence i.e. start with wall1, wall2, wall3, etc.

However, once wall1 has had 12 hrs to dry, I need to go back and start applying the second coat of paint to it once I finish whatever wall I am painting. For example say I am painting wall8, on completion I go back to wall1 to apply second coat once 12 hrs. of drying have elapsed.

After I finish the second coat on wall1, if wall2 has sat for 12hrs then I can apply the second coat to it too, if not, I go to wall9—the next in sequence before I went back to apply second coat to wall1. Again as soon as 12 hrs. of drying have elapsed for wall2, I go back and apply second coat once I am done with whatever wall I am painting at the time.

Is there a way in MS Project that I can apply dependencies to the drying time and sequence constraints in this logic so that at the end I have a full view of how long it will take me to complete the job given a certain calendar say no weekend work? The actual application is an earthworks project that has drying time and a fixed sequence for doing the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do this. This is a simplified example with four 'walls' (aka earthworks projects) that each take three 'coats of paint' (aka something that requires curing). Set up the schedule like shown in the picture and set the following:

- Change project calendar to be the work hours you need. In this example, I set 7-days-a-week, 9:00 AM to 5:00 PM.
- Make sure all tasks are auto-scheduled (not manually scheduled).
- Link each 'coat of paint' task to the prior coat using elapsed duration (e.g. calendar days/hours rather than working time).
- Link the first task of each subsequent 'wall' to the first task of the previous wall (in other words, don't like the summary tasks).
- Add a resource to do the work.

Once it is all set up the schedule should resemble this image. Note the red person icon on the left side of most tasks. This indicates that the resource is over-allocated.

[image: schedule before resource leveling]

Now here comes the power of using a scheduling engine like MS Project. Because the tasks are linked together in a way that represents the actual dependencies, we can use the [leveling feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/distribute-project-work-evenly-level-resource-assignments-59ee715d-4446-42c9-8756-4ea2a5a7e4a0) to move the tasks such that the resource is not over-allocated (e.g. double-booked to do more than one task at a time).

To level the resource(s), click Level All from the Resource tab. The task dates will move so that the resource is not over-allocated and the schedule will look like this:

[image: schedule after resource leveling]

Final note: be sure dates are not hard-coded--in other words, tasks should not have constraints such as 'Start No Earlier Than'.